# End the Game from a separate method

Tags: java

I have two different classes: TextBasedGame and IntroductionChoices.
IntroductionChoices makes all the decisions while TextBasedGame basically just prints the story (it's the one with the main method).

What I want to know is how to make the game END if the user makes a wrong choice.
In this case, if the user types in "Take down the group.", a message is displayed and the game ends. In my case, in the main method, it just keeps on going. How do I stop the game from running?

I was thinking I could somehow, in the main method, check if return from IntroductionChoicesis "GAME OVER" and end the game there.

```
   //Snippet from the main method
   System.out.println("What do you do?");    

   System.out.println(choice.choice1());

   System.out.println("Next part...");

   //Method choice1 from IntroductionChoices
   public static String choice1()
   {
       Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

       System.out.println("Warn her of her shadows.");
       System.out.println("Take down the group.");

       String decision = scan.next();

       if (decision.equalsIgnoreCase("right decision"))
       {
           System.out.println("some text");
        return "some more text in continuation to continue story in main";
       }

       else if (decision.equalsIgnoreCase("wrong decision"))
       {
           System.out.println("You creep towards the men, hoping to surprise them from behind.");

           System.out.println("Consequence");

           return "GAME OVER";
       }

       else
       {
           return "That is not a valid response.";
       }
}
```

Comment: I think you may wish to show the loop part of the `main` method. You could check the returned String (or some other value, such as an enum) in the main method.

Comment: you could simply just `throw` an `Exception` in your `choice()` method and catch it in your main

Comment: Can't you just test what was returned? `String choice = choice1(); if (choice.equals("GAME OVER")) return;`

Comment: show us how choice1() is called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
System.exit(0)


else if (decision.equalsIgnoreCase("wrong decision"))
{
    System.out.println("You creep towards the men, hoping to surprise them from behind.");

    System.out.println("Consequence");

    System.exit(0);
```

You won't need to return anything, it will end the program.

**OR**

Give the user an option:

1. Start new game-> start a new game
2. Quit ->  `System.exit(0)`

I'd also use a switch to check through the user options, you're less liekly to make mistakes and it can be neater and quicker when the options start accumulating.

You can create an enum of options or use final ints with meaningful names so your code is easier to navigate and then match with user options.

[From java the docs.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#exit-int-)

Comment: What if "ending the game" should allow to start another game?

Comment: @Bohemian, Couldn't you just ask user for input (do they want to start a new game), if no, System.exit, otherwise reset variables and call the starting function (which should be clearing variables anyways)?